# Configuration dialog is broken profoundly for all Gnome extensions

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell-extension

Regardless of what Gnome extension I try and what method I use to open the dialog, I get one of the three cases:

1. The text is missing completely.
2. Random letters are visible here and there. Controls are absent.
3. The first level dialog displays correctly but the second level options are all absent along with the controls.

Observed both on a freshly installed 22.04 and on a one upgraded from 20.04.4. Both Virtualbox VMs, of course. Saw a GTK error once: "No property margin on GtkGrid" - it may or may not be related. Example provided.

[image: dialog all messed up]

Comment: Are you using Wayland? Ubuntu 22.04 use Wayland by default.
I cant execute gnome-extensions-app if I use Wayland, I get "Error 71". With X11 works fine. I had to start a gnome session in X11, configure the extension, logout and start again a gnome session in Wayland. Changes had ben applied to extension.

Comment: Yes, it is broken on Xorg too. Tried the same old VM now with 22.04 updated to today's. Still the same random bugs.